# SSRS function returns #Error if value of field is null

Tags: reporting-services

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

My code is:

```
Public Function StripHTML(value As String) As String
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value, "<(.|\n)*?>", "")
End Function
```

Then I call the function from a textbox.  This works great unless there are nulls in the dataset.  I tried to compensate for the nulls, but the RDLC file generates an error message that it can't display the subreport.

```
Public Function StripHTML(value As String) As String
if isnothing(value) then return value 
else 
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value, "<(.|\n)*?>", "")
end if 
End Function
```

I also tried to tell it to return `"   "` if `null`.

I had no luck...

Any ideas?  and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set TextBox value to formula like this?

```
=iif(Fields!USER_TEST.Value is nothing,"-",StripHTML(Fields!USER_TEXT.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nullable types to check for nulls, it's supported from .net version 2.0 & above.

ex:

```
Nullable<int> x = null;

if (x.HasValue) Console.WriteLine("x is {0}", x.Value);
```